# Table dependencies and Flyway

Tags: sql, flyway, rollback

I have parent with child tables (that is dependent on the parent table). Do I need to create one SQL file for each child table and parent table? Or having one .sql file with parent and all its child tables?

If I include all create table statements in one SQL file, if any of the create table statement fails, will all the successful create table statements in the SQL file rollback?

Answer (score 0):

As to what gets rolled back depends actually on the database system in question.

Yes, putting all the tables into a single script means, again, depending, that when it fails, all will be rolled back. However, you can also put [transactions to work](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/testing-flyway-migrations-using-transactions) that will allow you to rollback sets of behaviors in multiple scripts, same as multiple statements in a single script.

In short, you can go either way. Generally, I would say that if you're deploying these tables as a piece of functionality. Say, version 1.1.1.42 of your app. Then they go together in a single change script and you deal with the rollback should the deploy fail (testing is your friend).

Comment: I'm using Snowflake. So, I'm using one sql and no trasaction (begin,end and commit) in my .sql. In that case, does Flyway rollback if my last create table command fails in the .sql. I'm going to test these. However, want to check . Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not a Snowflake expert, but my understanding, which could certainly be wrong, is that they'll all fail or rollback together if they're part of a single batch in a single file. However, as with all things, testing is your pal.